# "..for being so thoughtless."- What is the tense/grammar behind this formation?

Tags: grammar, tense

While reading a letter I found the sender wrote, "I hope you will forgive me **for being so thoughtless.**

If I rewrite it, should it look like,

- "*I hope you will forgive me because I was so thoughtless.*"
- "*I hope you will forgive me because what I did is wrong.*"

I was just wondering the part of the expression, **for being so thoughtless**; is that a present continuous tense! Not sure about the grammatical format.

Comment: Does your English dictionary tell you what the adjective _thoughtless_ means? Your two sentences are not exactly equivalent in meaning, but the word _thoughtless_ implies that the writer believes he or she acted improperly. The first sentence is closest to the meaning of the original. Yes: "Being so thoughless" is present continuous.

Comment: Hi, I found that you edited my question and makes it short. I will appreciate if you give an explanation for that change as well, because sometimes I write verbosely where I should be more careful I think. That was also an inline expression where I should pay my heed. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The exposition _"It was something he did was not right anyway!"_ has no bearing on the question of grammar.

Comment: Yes, :) I definitely know the meaning of 'thoughtless'. However, if I say, "It is something he did, is not right, anyway!" Whether its bear on the grammar? While we speak, actually we don't care about it, or we do care! 
As English is not my first language, sometimes something puzzled me made me stuck in my thought process.

I think, in academic writing, I can cope with successfully but while I write what usually I say, things are getting challenging.

So, a little bit more explanting would be highly appreciated in this verge.

Comment: You ask a very simple question. _"Being \[so\] thoughtless"_ is indeed the present continuous tense of the copula. Whether the letter writer did right or wrong, in your opinion, has no bearing on the question of grammar. We don't need to know about it to answer the question.

Comment: "You ask" or "You asked"! There is no 'right' or 'wrong' may be, but just the way of expression. I wrote those extra words to understand the underline situation. However, in academia, we try not to 'contradict' directly, like you said, 'you ask a very simple question.' Though it is simple but we practice to write it any other ways possible.

I am not good with that yet, therefore, my expressions are mostly exaggerated (I presume). And I also feel drops in the grammatical angle. 
Anyway, thanks for your kind time.

Answer (score 1):

People don't forgive you *because* you were thoughtless. The word **because** is misused there. Rather, they forgive *because* you are sorry.

**Because** introduces the reason for the action in the prior clause. It wants a clausal complement (*you are sorry*).

**for** introduces *what* is being forgiven.  *They forgave him **for** his misdeed.* The preposition **for** wants a nominal complement (*his misdeed*).

The nominal counterpart to **am thoughtless** or **was thoughtless** is **being thoughtless**.

They forgave him for **being thoughtless.**